# How I can use github LFS together with large size JSON server json?

Tags: json, github, git-lfs

So recently I create json server and I run into problem when I had to use LFS because of large size JSON files. So when I include these large json files to LFS, I couldn't use these JSON files anymore due to error:

```
SyntaxError: /var/www/html/largejson.json: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
```

So json server doesn't recognize json files anymore because it's been kind of recognized as javaScript. What solution I could have?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  A JSON object is valid Javascript with no changes requires.  That's the very essence of the name: "JavaScript Object Notation".  Where did the `v` come from as the first character of your file?

Comment: The problem lies within the github LFS reference. LFS creates a reference of the file, for example, if you put package.json to LFS you won't be able to use "npm install" even though the file is there, the content of the file somehow becomes a link of LFS storage. Though if I open it, it shows a regular package.json content. But if I open it with Linux ```cat``` command it shows the LFS link...

Comment: That means if I use  `git lfs track "*.json" `    all json files will be blocked in json server. But I need them in github and in json server. Here is a [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com) link

Comment: "Though if I open it, it shows a regular package.json content" -- How do you open it that it works, if `cat` doesn't?

Comment: @TimRoberts If I open it in the editor. In GitHub it says `View raw` and you can only then download it